# Close menu on container scroll

Tags: reactjs, typescript, select, react-select

I want to close the react-select menu when scrolling a container outside of the select control. There is a `closeMenuOnScroll` prop in the official react-select documentation which states the following:
[closeMenuOnScroll prop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UBhYw.png)

However, when I set `closeMenuOnScroll={() => true}` prop on the `<Select />` component, it closes the menu even if I scroll inside of it (I can't scroll the menu options, because it is automatically closed).

```
<Select
   options={options}
   closeMenuOnScroll={() => true}
/>
```

What I try to achieve is **to go through (scroll) the menu items** when I scroll inside the react-select component and **close the menu** if I scroll out of it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Like the documentation says :

If true, close the select menu when the user scrolls the document/body.
If a function, takes a standard javascript ScrollEvent you return a boolean:
true => The menu closes
false => The menu stays open

https://react-select.com/props

so your code has to be like this:

```
closeMenuOnScroll={e => {
    if (e.target === document) {
      return true
    } else {
      return false
    }
  }}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess its too late but here is a solution to your issue.

```js
 closeMenuOnScroll={(e) => {
                  if (e.target.className === " css-4ljt47-MenuList") {
                    return false;
                  } else {
                    return true;
                  }
                }}
```

Here in my case " css-4ljt47-MenuList" is my menuList's className.

and this works smooth.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
closeMenuOnScroll={e =>
    !e.target.classList.contains('css-4ljt47-MenuList')
     }
```

Comment: Although this code might answer the question, I recommend that you also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.